# If a good choice of a unit cell should be the one of most symmetry ,then why keep body centered tetragonal if face centered cubic exists?

Tags: crystal-structure, lattices, bravais-lattices

For any lattice a good choice of a unit cell is the one that is the most symmetric.

Now if every lattice made by a body centered tetragonal unit cell can be made by a face centered cubic unit cell ,which is more symmetric ,then why keep the body centered tetragonal unit cell as a class of Bravais lattice ?
[image]

Comment: Because **not** every body centered tetragonal cell is equivalent to a face centered cubic cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Body-centered tetragonal is face-centered cubic only if $c/a=\sqrt2$.  If you try your transformation with a $c/a$ value greater/less than $\sqrt2$, your "cube" will have lateral edges that are longer/shorter (resp.) than the basal edge and so really remains tetragonal.

You can also read this the other way.  If you are presented with a body-centered tetragonal lattice and $c/a$ seems to be close to $\sqrt2$, maybe it's really fcc.